# Closing PDO connection inside function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In [this PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) it gives the following example of how to close a connection:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
// use the connection here


// and now we're done; close it
$dbh = null;
```

But what if I'm using it in a function where `$dbh` has only local scope, do I have to set it to null, or will the connection close when the function returns?

In my below example, is the connection closed?

```
public function doDBWork(){
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    // use the connection here

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> you [close the connection] by assigning `NULL` to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

So the connection will not be closed at the end of the function since you did not assign `null`. Although it is inaccessible since its scope is local to the function, it technically won't be *closed* until the end of the script.

**Note:** In general, I don't recommend establishing and closing database connections within function calls.

Answer (score 1):

PHP PDO manage the connection for you. You can make sure that connection will be closed setting null to PDO connection object. But isn't necessary.

In you case, you aren't using your connection to make querys, and when the method end the connection will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking setting `$dbh` to null doesn't close the connection. This will make the PDO instance eligible for garbage collection (as long as there aren't any other references to the object). Presumably the destructor for PDO cleans up the connection.

To answer your question your example will close the connection (or at least act in the same way as the first example) because once again `$dbh` will be eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the DB handle as an argument to a global function (or static method). But it is really unnecessary. The DB handle is automatically closed when code execution ends. No need to explicitly close it.

```
function close_connection(PDO $dbh) {
   $dbh = null;
}
```

Comment: I'm working on a script where database connectivity is limited (due to server load restrictions). So the connection should only be open for a short while (in the function).

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be dependency injection so that you don't have to open multiple connections.

```
class MyClass {
    protected $PDO;

    public function __construct(PDO $PDO) {
        $this->PDO = $PDO;
    }

    public function DoDbWork() {
        $this->PDO->Query(); //uses same PDO instance that was supplied outside class
    }
}

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

//call multiple functions, do stuff procedurely, etc.
$t = new MyClass($dbh);
$t->DoDbWork();

$dbh = null;
```